# Spring security +Jsf2

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, spring-security

I'm newbie at spring security it's my first use to spring security at me APP
My application has developed using jsf2 , primefaces , spring , hibernate 
after developing it I'm trying to integrate it with Spring security framework 
there are two problems 
1- when access any URL from app , my app isn't navigate him to login page 
2- when one user logged in and someone else tried to access the application in the same time , he see that someone is logged in and conflicts are happenned and at end throw exceptions meaning there is no new created session for the second user

My applicationContext-Security.xml is

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/jdbc.properties" />
    <!-- For Spring auto wiring -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="main.com.zc.attSys" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <http use-expressions="true">

        <form-login login-page="/pages/courseFeedBack/ask/login.xhtml"  
            authentication-failure-url="/pages/courseFeedBack/ask/login.xhtml" />

    </http>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

my web.xml is :

```
  <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.conf

    ig.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
        </listener>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener> 

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name> <param-value>none</param-value> 
        </context-param> -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>




    <context-param>

        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

        <param-value>
             /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml

        </param-value>

    </context-param>
<session-config>
       <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

any help please ?

Comment: try to start with <http auto-config="true"/> only, this will create a basic login page. when that works then gradually add a custom login page, etc.  what is the error/behaviour when it does not redirect to login, anything on the screen/logs? if there is a stacktrace can you post it as well

Comment: I've tried it but the same
The error in behavior , he redirect to home page not to the login Page at first

Comment: You should start with the sample applications that come with Spring Security. I would leave JSF out of it if at all possible too, at least to begin with (preferably forever). I wouldn't recommend using "auto-config" either, as it is just confusing. Just use what you require and configure it manually. But start with the samples so you have a working example. From there you can experiment and ask more specific questions.